# How can I create a dip molding process in Blender?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to create an animation including something similar to [dip molding process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pHdG5drqgk):

[image]

An object goes inside a highly thick/viscous liquid and comes out. Some of the liquid sticks to the surface and then dries out. I would appreciate if you could point me to the right tutorials if there are any.

Comment: You might play around a bit with "Dynamic Paint", but I suspect you will need to add some trickery when you create your animation. Something like modelling the drips on the dipped part and hiding them until the part is pulled out.

Comment: well, it is not for a real professional animation. so even without the driplets it should be ok.